# automatic PDF invoice with FPDF in PHP (creating Wordpress Plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, fpdf

I hope someone can help me. 
**What I would like to achieve:**
I would like to create an automatic PDF invoice, as soon as an order has taken place and download it to a folder. It DOES NOT have to be displayed.
**My problem:**
I'm only concerned about the PDF creation. Somehow I can not create and download the PDF. I already read through similar questions on the subject here, but was not able to figure out the issue.
**What I've done so far:**
I have a plugin, into which the automatic billing has to be integrated. Within the plugin folder (.../wp-content/plugins/myplugin/) I have created a folder fpdf and installed fpdf.
The fpdf.php is located in ... /myplugin/fpdf/fpdf.php
I have created a file with the following code for testing. This is also in the fpdf folder (... /myplugin/fpdf/pdf_creation.php):

```
<?php
require(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'fpdf/fpdf.php');   
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');

//$filename = '/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/rechnungen/rechnung.pdf';
//$pdf->Output($filename,'F');

//testing output
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

**What I get:**
If I try to open the PDF directly in the browser, I get a http ERROR 500 (Chrome), in Firefox a white page.

I hope that one of you can help me.
Best regards

Comment: there is a site for WordPress developement questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can't use wordpress' functions in a file that is not included through wordpress. The reason you get an error 500 (internal server error) is that calling the wordpress-function `plugin_dir_path` outside of wordpress (ie. when accessing the php-file directly) will give you a fatal error because it simply does not exist!

To get some hints for fatal errors (that typically just show a blank page and response code 500) make sure you enable `display_errors` as the first thing:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//...other code here
```

> Make sure to **remove it when you are done with development** - you don't want to accidentally disclose sensitive information by having this on permanently!

As for actually going "around" wordpress to create the PDF, it's probably no the best idea in the first place - because you will probably need access to a lot of other wordpress functions later on.

What I like to do is something like this:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test plugin
Plugin URI: 
Description: Whatever
Version: 0.01
Author: Mikk3lRo
*/

myplugin::init();

class myplugin {
    static function init() {
        register_activation_hook(__FILE__,      array(__CLASS__, 'on_activate'));
        register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__,    array(__CLASS__, 'on_deactivate'));
        add_action('init',                      array(__CLASS__, 'rewrites'));
        add_filter('query_vars',                array(__CLASS__, 'query_vars'));
        add_filter('template_redirect',         array(__CLASS__, 'get_pdf'),0);
    }
    static function on_activate() {
        self::rewrites();
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
    static function on_deactivate() {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
    static function rewrites() {
        /* This basically catches everything
           below http://yourdomain.com/get-pdf/
           and passes it to your pdf-generating
           script, so your URL's can be:
           http://yourdomain.com/get-pdf/invoice-1.pdf
           http://yourdomain.com/get-pdf/My-invoice-for-you.pdf
           ...or whatever your like... */
        add_rewrite_rule('get-pdf', 'index.php?myplugin_show_pdf=true', 'top');
    }
    static function query_vars($vars) {
        $vars[] = 'myplugin_show_pdf';
        return $vars;
    }
    static function get_pdf() {
        if (get_query_var('myplugin_show_pdf')) {
            include_once __DIR__ . '/get_pdf.php';
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can do whatever you need in `get_pdf.php` with full access to the normal wordpress environment:

```
<?php
$pdf_slug = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

require(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'fpdf/fpdf.php');   
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'This is the pdf for: ' . $pdf_slug);

//$pdf->Output($filename,'F');
$pdf->Output();
die();
```

On a side note I'd recommend using [TCPDF](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf) instead - it's a fork of FPDF that has better supports for UTF8 among some other improvements. At this point of your development it should be pretty easy to switch.